# Is column order reliable in UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, update

Can we reply on the order of columns in an `UPDATE`?

```
SET @x = 0
UPDATE table1 SET
col1=IF(col1 IS NULL, NULL, @x:=@x+col1), 
col2=IF(col2 IS NULL, NULL, @x:=@x+col2),
col3=IF(col3 IS NULL, NULL, @x:=0)
```

Is it guaranteed that `col1` is `UPDATE`d before `col2`?

I do care about the order in calculating the value `@x`.

Comment: The [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) state - *Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right. For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that assignments are carried out in any particular order.*. So In stating that multi-table updates are not guaranteed to be in any particular order it seems to imply that single table updates are, however, stating they are "**generally** evaluated from left to right" doesn't fill me with confidence!

Comment: @GarethD my case is single table, is there a guarantee that `UPDATE` is from left to right? as we can use `ORDER BY` for single table, but not multiple-tables?

Answer (score 4):

The order is unreliable and is subject to change on different query evaluation plans.

However, I found a reliable hack around this. Please consider my presentation [Programmatic Queries: Things you can Code with MySQL](http://www.slideshare.net/shlominoach/programmatic-queries-thingsyoucancodewithsql). In particular see slides 10 - 15.

The trick presented utilizes the known order of evaluation in a `CASE` clause, as follows:

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN (@c3 := @c1 + @c2) IS NULL THEN NULL
    WHEN (@c1 := @c2) IS NULL THEN NULL
    WHEN (@c2 := @c3) IS NULL THEN NULL
    ELSE @c3
  END AS seq
FROM 
  mysql.help_topic, 
  (SELECT @c1 := 1, @c2 := 0) s_init
LIMIT 10;
```

The `CASE` expression *has to* evaluate the `WHEN` clauses by order of appearance (to be more specific, it *does* so, and it doesn't make sense to do otherwise).

In the above none of the `WHEN` expressions make for a *true* value, which is why the `CASE` clause keeps evaluating them *one by one*. This gives you your required order.

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand how it works. I made an example on sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12b797/5/1 Could you give me a helping hand in getting the same result as the first query in the column group_wise_row_number? The second query is my attempt. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what it is that you are trying to achieve. If you explain that, I can help you.

Comment: Oh, got it. Looking into.

Comment: Done. Please see updated fiddle

Comment: hrrmmmm... overriden. This is the `case` clause: `case when (if(@prev != groups, @row:=1, @row:=@row+1)) is null then null
when (@prev := groups) is null then null
else @row
end`

Comment: Ah, in the hurry and all the editing I forgot the second `when`. Thanks and +1 :)

Comment: Your "reliable hack" runs afoul of the [confirmation](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=47516) that you yourself elicited from bugs.mysql.com that reading and writing the same variable in the same SELECT statement text is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @philipxy thank you. My hack came to solve that very problem. Bear in mind that the clauses in a `case` clause make their own statements and are evaluated in-order independently of the outside statement. While you do not know if your entire `case` statement is in or out of order with other columns, the `WHEN` statements execute reliably one after the other.

Comment: You misuse "statement". An SQL statement is an entire update, query, etc. (With ";".) (Anyway, what is in a nested expression is in its containing expression.) Also (the unclear) [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) does not support your execution claims. Assignment expressions are *not* tied to conceptual execution of a statement (which doesn't iterate over rows anyway). Eg "the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined", "each select expression is evaluated only when sent to the client". (I'll post a clarification bug.)

Comment: PS I get the attitude of your slides where you are writing code under a particular implementation, accepting/assuming certain implementation-determined operator, optimizer & non-deterministic function call semantics. I am interested in the *specified* behaviour. (If there even is any.) (Eg PostgresSQL happens to document/guarantee certain per-statement & per-row non-deterministic function call semantics.)

Comment: If my hack would comply with the _specified behavior_ it would be named a "solution", not a "hack" :)

Comment: The documentation does not support my claims, the MySQL source code does. Whether you wish to rely on this or not is of course your legitimate choice. Insofar it held true for over `7` years, and who knows whether this will change next year or in `2045`.

Answer (score 3):

To quote the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html):

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. For example, to increment a variable, this is okay:

```
SET @a = @a + 1;
```

> For other statements, such as SELECT, **you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed**. In the following statement, you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an assignment second:

```
SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;
```

> However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.
>
> Another issue with assigning a value to a variable and reading the value within the same non-SET statement is that the default result type of a variable is based on its type at the start of the statement. The following example illustrates this:

```
mysql> SET @a='test';
mysql> SELECT @a,(@a:=20) FROM tbl_name;
```

> For this SELECT statement, MySQL reports to the client that column one is a string and converts all accesses of @a to strings, even though @a is set to a number for the second row. After the SELECT statement executes, @a is regarded as a number for the next statement.

Comment: I totally understand the unreliability you quoted, but for a simple arithmetic mentioned in the question, a guaranteed order of `UPDATE` can satisfy the user variable re-SET. Ain't it?

Comment: Personally I can say, that I use user variables very often, for selects as well as updates, and the behaviour has always been as expected. Still I use them just for queries where I can control the result, not in application code, simply because of the above quoted. You can use them and I'd bet you get the correct result, but don't blame me if not.