# Reset Variable when row value is changed

Tags: mysql

Below is an example of a `SELECT` statement. I have a variable `@total` that is set to `0`, which works fine if I am doing a `WHERE` clause but I need the final total for each agent. Currently how this works is that each agent's records display and their total at the end. My question is how can I reset the variable when the `agentID` changes to the next agent and only display the final count.

```
select agentID, points,  
@total:= @total + points AS Total, comment 
from attendance, (select @total:= 0) v group by agentID, incurredDate
```

This is what I am trying to achieve.

```
=======================
agentID    |    total
=======================
brwilson   |      2
vimunson   |      5
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d53222/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select agentID,points,
case when (if(@prev_agent != agentID, @total := points, @total := @total + points)) is null then null
when (@prev_agent := agentID) is null then null
else @total end as running_total
, comment 
from attendance, (select @total:= 0.0, @prev_agent:=null) v 
order by agentID, incurredDate
```

- see it working live in an [<kbd>sqlfiddle</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f789/3/0)

In case you wonder, why I use this `case when` construct, please refer to this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/56460/7867).

P.S.: When using variables like this, you should have a `order by` clause. `Group by` in MySQL uses an implicit `order by` when none is specified. But remember using `order by` when you don't have a `group by`.

EDIT: Actually your `group by`doesn't fit here, it seems to me. I changed it to a `order by`. And I changed your points column to datatype decimal(5,2), cause you have `.5` in your sample data, which would become `1` when you continue to use `int`.

**EDIT:**

To get the total for each agent, just wrap above query in another query like this:

```
select agentID, MAX(running_total)
from (
    select agentID,points,
    case when (if(@prev_agent != agentID, @total := points, @total := @total + points)) is null then null
    when (@prev_agent := agentID) is null then null
    else @total end as running_total
    , comment 
    from attendance, (select @total:= 0.0, @prev_agent:=null) v 
    order by agentID, incurredDate
) sq
GROUP BY agentID
```

- see it working live in an [<kbd>sqlfiddle</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f789/11/0)